# Setting behaviour of Floating Action Button programmatically

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, floating-action-button, android-support-design

I'm using the following guide to implement a scroll aware FAB:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons#overview

After creating the class, you set up the behaviour by declaring it in XML as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton    
app:layout_behavior="com.codepath.floatingactionbuttontest.ScrollAwareFABBehavior" />
```

Due to how my code is written, I want to set the behaviour programmatically and not in the XML. I have a feeling that this is done with the CoordinatorLayout but I'm drawing a blank.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use somenthing like this:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
p.setBehavior(xxxx);
fab.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Comment: It seems that "fab.setLayoutParams(p);" is unnecessary since the "p" points to the LayoutParams object and the calling to "p.setBehavior(xxxx);" is sufficient.

Comment: @AlanZhiliangFeng I can't test it right now; are you sure about this? Of course it makes sense strictly from OOP perspective, but this class represents *layout* params... changing its properties may require layout recalculation, so it would make sense for the getter to return a mere "copy" which needs to be "reapplied" after modifying.

Comment: By checking the source you can tell that both of you are correct. Yes, it calculates stuff when setting `LayoutParams`, but also those stuff don't care about the behavior object being changed so I would go with @Gabriele Mariotti's full solution just in case the API changes in the future.